# LinkerD side car show certificate expired but in LinkerD check certificate shown as valid

Tags: linkerd

- The LinkerD installed with cert-manager and prepare all linkerd namespaces with their respective issuers and certificates with automatic renewal.
- The command ./linkerd check does not show any error.
- The issuers - linkerd-trust-anchor and webhook-issuer are valid
- The certificates linkerd-identity-issuer, linkerd-policy-validator, linkerd-proxy-injector, linkerd-sp-validator also valid and not expires.

When I try to apply policy A receive error:

> Error from server (InternalError): error when creating
> ".\templates\servers.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling
> webhook "linkerd-policy-validator.linkerd.io": Post
> "https://linkerd-policy-validator.linkerd.svc:443/?timeout=10s": x509:
> certificate has expired or is not yet valid

And there is error "Failed to connect error=invalid certificate: CertExpired" in side car container log:

> [     0.000771s]  INFO ThreadId(01) linkerd2_proxy::rt: Using
> single-threaded proxy runtime [     0.001299s]  INFO ThreadId(01)
> linkerd2_proxy: Admin interface on 0.0.0.0:4191 [     0.001311s]  INFO
> ThreadId(01) linkerd2_proxy: Inbound interface on 0.0.0.0:4143 [
> 0.001313s]  INFO ThreadId(01) linkerd2_proxy: Outbound interface on 127.0.0.1:4140 [     0.001314s]  INFO ThreadId(01) linkerd2_proxy: Tap interface on 0.0.0.0:4190 [     0.001316s]  INFO ThreadId(01)
> linkerd2_proxy: Local identity is
> gpproxyserver-tlm.rainbowstaging-main.serviceaccount.identity.linkerd.cluster.local [     0.001321s]  INFO ThreadId(01) linkerd2_proxy: Identity verified
> via linkerd-identity-headless.linkerd.svc.cluster.local:8080
> (linkerd-identity.linkerd.serviceaccount.identity.linkerd.cluster.local)
> [     0.001323s]  INFO ThreadId(01) linkerd2_proxy: Destinations
> resolved via linkerd-dst-headless.linkerd.svc.cluster.local:8086
> (linkerd-destination.linkerd.serviceaccount.identity.linkerd.cluster.local)
> [     0.003971s]  WARN ThreadId(01)
> policy:watch{port=4191}:controller{addr=linkerd-policy.linkerd.svc.cluster.local:8090}:endpoint{addr=192.168.163.207:8090}:
> rustls::session: Sending fatal alert BadCertificate     [
> 0.004033s]  WARN ThreadId(01) policy:watch{port=4191}:controller{addr=linkerd-policy.linkerd.svc.cluster.local:8090}:endpoint{addr=192.168.163.207:8090}:
> linkerd_reconnect: Failed to connect error=invalid certificate:
> CertExpired [     0.032277s]  INFO ThreadId(02) daemon:identity:
> linkerd_app: Certified identity:
> gpproxyserver-tlm.rainbowstaging-main.serviceaccount.identity.linkerd.cluster.local [    24.056844s]  WARN ThreadId(01)
> inbound:server{port=8000}:controller{addr=linkerd-dst-headless.linkerd.svc.cluster.local:8086}:endpoint{addr=192.168.163.207:8086}:
> rustls::session: Sending fatal alert BadCertificate     [
> 24.057004s]  WARN ThreadId(01) inbound:server{port=8000}:controller{addr=linkerd-dst-headless.linkerd.svc.cluster.local:8086}:endpoint{addr=192.168.163.207:8086}:
> linkerd_reconnect: Failed to connect error=invalid certificate:
> CertExpired [    24.074130s]  WARN ThreadId(01)
> outbound:server{orig_dst=10.98.31.55:5672}: rustls::session: Sending
> fatal alert BadCertificate     [    24.132043s]  INFO ThreadId(01)
> inbound:server{port=8000}: linkerd_proxy_http::upgrade: tcp duplex
> error: client: Broken pipe (os error 32) [  2117.365594s]  WARN
> ThreadId(01)
> inbound:server{port=8000}:controller{addr=linkerd-dst-headless.linkerd.svc.cluster.local:8086}:endpoint{addr=192.168.163.207:8086}:
> rustls::session: Sending fatal alert BadCertificate     [
> 2117.369126s]  WARN ThreadId(01) inbound:server{port=8000}:controller{addr=linkerd-dst-headless.linkerd.svc.cluster.local:8086}:endpoint{addr=192.168.163.207:8086}:
> linkerd_reconnect: Failed to connect error=invalid certificate:
> CertExpired [  2117.377137s]  WARN ThreadId(01)
> outbound:server{orig_dst=10.98.31.55:5672}: rustls::session: Sending
> fatal alert BadCertificate     [  2117.388693s]  INFO ThreadId(01)
> inbound:server{port=8000}: linkerd_proxy_http::upgrade: tcp duplex
> error: client: Broken pipe (os error 32)